# print icon obtained from db - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to put together a menu and get an icon dynamically.

**the result i want is something like this:**
[image]

Database table:

[image]

code:

```html
 <div class="card card-dashboard-eight">
    <label class="main-content-label mb-1">Categoryes</label>
    <span class="d-block mg-b-20 text-muted">Stores All</span>
    <div class="list-group">
      @foreach($tipos as $tipo)
      <div class="list-group-item">
        {{$tipo->icono }}
        <p><a href="{{url('/category/type/'.$tipo->tipo)}}">{{$tipo->tipo }}</a></p>
      </div>
      @endforeach
     
   
     
    </div>
  </div>
```

but it prints the label not the icon

[image]

What should I do to show my icons?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know the template engine you are using, but it seems to escape the html chars. maybe it just works by removing the double brackets ("{$tipo->icono}" instead of "{{$tipo->icono }}").

But for app-design reasons: i'd suggest to store just the type (or class) in the database. not an html-tag. meaning: the column "icono" should just contain f.e. "glass-martini" - instead of a complete html-tag. put the html-stuff in your template and add the class from your column there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `{!! !!}` to display the raw unescaped HTML of your icon:

```
{!! $tipo->icono !!}
```

This way it doesn't get escaped with `htmlspecialchars`.

Basically `{{ $var }}` will be compiled to `<?php htmlspecialchars($var); ?>` and `{!! $var !!}` to `<?php echo $var; ?>`.

See the docs on how to [display data in Blade templates](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#displaying-data) for more information.